# Trying to manipulate member function pointer inside the same class

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I am trying to use pointer to member function for dynamic access thru a linked list. (I am studying C++ since a few months)

A made a class. The class constructor build a linked list. Each node contain some data, pointer to next node, and pointer a to function (I am trying this last one... not working for now)

I am able to use the pointer to member function in the constructor BUT I don't understand how to pass this pointer value to other structures or functions. Maybe I miss something easy...

Thanks in advance for your help.

- Trying to use the right syntax for pointer to member function
- Trying some different syntax to pass the value as an argument to function

---

```
class linkedFct{
private:
    struct node *firstNode;
    struct node *lastNode;
    struct node *newNode;
    struct node *currentNode;
public:
    linkedFct(){
        firstNode = (NULL); 
        lastNode = (NULL);

        void (linkedFct::*ptrFct)();        
        ptrFct = &linkedFct::theFunctionA;  
        //Call the function by pointer... this works!!! Great!
        (this->*ptrFct)();
        //Add a first node to the list          
        addNode("Try a first task");            
        //addNode("Try a first task", &(this->*ptrFct()));
        //Trying to include the member function pointer into the list data
        //this is not working!!! Don't understand how to pass that pointer
        //to a member function
    }

    void addNode(string aName){ 
    //void addNode(string aName, void (linkedFct::*ptrF)()){
            //I am trying to implement something like this
            //Trying to pass a member function pointer thru this attribute
        newNode = new node; 
        newNode->name = aName;
        //newNode->ptrFunction = ptrF;          //Trying to implement something like this***
        lastNode = newNode; 
        if (!firstNode){
            firstNode = newNode;
        }
        else{
            currentNode->nextNode = newNode;
        }
        currentNode = newNode;


};
```

---

Trying to use the pointer inside the list... mmm... not working that way

---

```
void processTheList(){                      //Browse the list
    struct node *thisCurrentNode;
    void (linkedFct::*ptrRunFct)();
    thisCurrentNode = firstNode;                //Start from top
    int i = 0;
    while (thisCurrentNode){
        i++;
        cout << "Node #" << i << ": Name: " << thisCurrentNode->name << endl;   //Print the string
        ptrRunFct = thisCurrentNode->ptrFunction;
        ptrRunFct();
        cout << endl;
        thisCurrentNode = thisCurrentNode->nextNode;
    }
}
```

---

The node struct is defined that way:

---

```
struct node{                            //A node struct to implement a linked list
    string name;                        //Some data
    void (linkedFct::*ptrFunction)();   //A pointer to member function... ****[That's what I am trying!!!]****
    struct node *nextNode;              //Pointer to next node
};
```

Comment: `addNode("Try a first task", ptrFct);`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with `void addNode(string aName, void (linkedFct::*ptrF)())`. When you say it isn't working what problem did you have?

Comment: @melpomene I think this works that way. I don't know why I didn't try like this at first. Maybe I did and I got confused with another compiling mistake.